# Is there a way in React Native to use event.target?

Tags: react-native

I was looking for an answer to my question but couldn't find anything yet. So, is there a way to access event.target in React Native? Or how can I do something similar, I need this because I want to convert my Web App from React in React Native.

There was a way before win ReactNativeComponentTree but that thing was deleted in the newer version of RN.

Comment: have you tried ```useRef()``` ?

Comment: I will try that and see what happens

Comment: @IonutC.Kevin. Did you find a solution?
Please check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64023220/event-target-value-in-react-native